# Proper way to release an instance variable in dealloc, Objective C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, instance-variables, accessor, dealloc

I have been wondering about the proper way to release an instance variable in `dealloc` method of a class. Suppose I have an instance variable named myString,

```
// MyClass.h
{
NSString *myString;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *myString;

// MyClass.m
@synthesize myString;

-(void)dealloc
{
[self setMyString: nil]; 
[super dealloc];
}
```

Apple documentation states that `Don’t Use Accessor Methods in Initializer Methods and dealloc`. I found some inputs that setting the instance variable to nil does the job for releasing the instance variable(which I am doing in above `dealloc` method). So, if this is the correct way to release an instance variable then why Apple says that it not advisable to use accessors in `dealloc` method?

Comment: The proper way, IMHO, is to use `ARC`

Answer (score 3):

You should call release in on the object;

```
-(void)dealloc {
   [myString release], myString = nil;
   [super dealloc];
}
```

It has to do with multithreading, where there might be some other thread also accessing the property.

But you should really more to `ARC`, then you do not have to add `dealloc` to any of your object and the compiler will add retain/release message for you art compile time.

Apple has released a nice  [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: what is the difference between what you wrote and [self setMyString: nil];? i don't see any

Comment: He used `[xyz release]` too.

Comment: @AndreyChernukha: You are calling a setter method. There are some issues of doing that in `dealloc` in relation to Key-Value Coding.

Comment: With ARC, you could still implement a dealloc method to do other cleanup, though simply assigning to ivar to nil is unnecessary.  And with ARC, you should not include [super dealloc]